# How to call instantiated class from main.cpp in another cpp file with qt - c++

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, instance

My **modBusSHARED** variable is a variable that i will need in some class .cpp.

Ho to call them from main.cpp anytime i want without re-instance?
Maybe i need a singleton ? There is a method in qt that I call class from main without build singleton?

I'm using Qt 5.9.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    ModbusMasterMobile modBusSHARED;
    bool test = modBusSHARED.connectWIFITCP("xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx", 1234, 3000);

    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec(); 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the variable to either the constructor of your class or the methods of your class?

Comment: Yes, but pass the variable it's not my target...my target is call the class when i want from cpp....maybe the unique solution is singleton.

Comment: Let's say your class is `Car`, and `Car` needs a `Driver` (from `main`).  You create a member in `Car` that is a reference to a `Driver`.  The `Car` constructor would have a `Driver` reference as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `static ModbusMasterMobile * modbus;` your other class and initialize it to `&modBusSHARED` as soon as the latter is created.

Then you will have access to that object from all instances of the other class.

Having a singleton is to prevent accidentally creating more than once instance of that type. But your situation doesn't really merit a singleton, all you need to do is simply not create any more instances of that object. Once you initialize the static pointer, it will point to that one instance.

```
// in Class.h
class Class {
  public:
  static ModbusMasterMobile * modbus; // now you can use modbus inside Class
  // ... other stuff
};

// in Class.cpp
ModbusMasterMobile * Class::modbus = 0;

// in main.cpp
ModbusMasterMobile modBusSHARED;
Class::modbus = &modbus; // initialize it
// from this point on Class can use modbus
```

Just make sure `Class` doesn't use `modbus` before it is initialized in `main.cpp`.